# Wrap native int[] into a jintarray

Tags: android, arrays, java-native-interface, native, primitive

I have a native method which calls a Java function to create a bitmap, then returns the bitmap data as array of int.

The method isn't very efficient, because I need to create a Bitmap, then an IntBuffer to copy the bitmap data, then the native method creates a new int array to store the data. The IntBuffer is then recycled (the Bitmap object could be reused), and when I create more than 10 bitmaps, the garbage collector starts slowing down the application.

Can I just create the int array in JNI, wrap it into a jintarray and use it directly in Java?

Comment: `int[]` gets mapped to `jintArray` in JNI, there's nothing special that we need to do.

Comment: Yes and no, a Java int[] is a jintArray in JNI, but a native (C++) int[] isn't.

Comment: Ah, you should make it clear that you were talking about a C++ `int[]`. We can get one from a `jintArray` by calling `GetIntArrayElements()`. But yeah if you want to go the other way around, `NewDirectByteBuffer()` is what you are looking for indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

I can wrap a native int* (or char*) into a ByteBuffer using the JNI function NewDirectByteBuffer. Then use it as a parameter, instead of the jintarray.